# iPhone to WatchKit Communication

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I am able to send data from Watch to Parent app with

```
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:applicationData reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {}]
```

api but how to send data from iPhone to Watch in Objective C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some ways to achieve that. The easiest  one is using [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole).

You send data using:

```
[self.wormhole passMessageObject:@{@"titleString" : title} 
                      identifier:@"messageIdentifier"];
```

and you receive it using:

```
[self.wormhole listenForMessageWithIdentifier:@"messageIdentifier" 
 listener:^(id messageObject) {
    // Do Something
}];
```

Note that wormhole uses app groups to communicate, so you need to enable it.

What MMWormhole uses, under the hood, is `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter`. The implementation is simple and if you want to do your own implementation you have more info about `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter` [in this medium post](https://medium.com/@saberjack/ios-sending-notifications-between-your-apps-3fe7422d6a41%20.).

Answer (score 0):

Any code executed in your WatchKit Extension is done on your phone, the watch basically acts as sort of external screen